# Проблемы с jquery.resize()

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Я хочу сделать непрерывный ресайз изображения, но размеры меняются только после обновления страницы. В чем проблема?

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(img).css({
        width:  $('item').width()  * coef + 'px' ,
        height: $('item').height() * coef + 'px'
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dpxqf3v7/ тут более полный код, нужно только выбрать версию библиотеки, например 1.7.2

Comment: @lekh-v, что в переменной `img`? Что за элемент `'item'`? Откуда берётся `coef`? Выложите полный код примера на jsfiddle.net.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/dpxqf3v7/  там еще слева нужно выбрать версию JQuery 1.7.2 ,например.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел код, чесно скажу, вы что-то непонятное накодили и очень странными методами, но не суть :)

Ваша пролема в том, что вместо уже определенной переменной вы используете селектор:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$(img).css({
    width:  $('item').width()  * coef + 'px' ,
    height: $('item').height() * coef + 'px'
});
});
```

А нужно

```
$(window).resize(function(){
$(img).css({
    width:  item.width()  * coef + 'px' ,
    height: item.height() * coef + 'px'
});
});
```

Тогда resize заработает.

Comment: Да, вы правы, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

А вам обязательно использовать для этого Jquery? Можно ведь без скриптов делать ресайз картинки в блоке при изменении окна браузера:

http://jsfiddle.net/1z0n3L2v/ - по ширине

http://jsfiddle.net/1z0n3L2v/1/ - по ширине и высоте

Comment: JQuery использовать обязательно, так как я хочу расширить готовый touchslider, чтобы фото можно было загружать разных размеров и они бы пропорционально изменялись под один контейнер. Соль в том, что изображений там несколько, и, если они разного размера, то это будет смотреться очень плохо.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1z0n3L2v/2/ я имел ввиду, что в решении данного вопроса нет необходимости использовать jquery, вот вам пример с нескольким картинками :) проблема с изображениями разного размера тоже решается, их можно выравнивать по высоте, а ширину брать автоматом

Comment: Если в тачслайдерах использовать данный метод, то  либо изображения уродуются, либо страница. Мне необходим именно resize